# Run Queued jobs in Laravel 5 without command line listener?

Tags: laravel-5, redis, laravel-queue

I have been adding jobs to a queue in Laravel, but they are only running when I am ssh'ed into the server and run the following command:

```
php artisan queue:listen --tries 1 --timeout=60
```

I need for the queue to run constantly, without relying on the command line listener above. The queue is running through redis, and the only configuration that I have so far is:

```
config.php

 'queue' => 
  array (
    'default' => 'redis',
    'connections' => 
    array (
      'sync' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'sync',
      ),
      'database' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'laravel_jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
      ),
      'beanstalkd' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'ttr' => 60,
      ),
      'sqs' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'sqs',
        'key' => 'your-public-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret-key',
        'queue' => 'your-queue-url',
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
      ),
      'iron' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'iron',
        'host' => 'mq-aws-us-east-1.iron.io',
        'token' => 'your-token',
        'project' => 'your-project-id',
        'queue' => 'your-queue-name',
        'encrypt' => true,
      ),
      'redis' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'expire' => 60,
      ),
    ),
    'failed' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'mysql',
      'table' => 'laravel_failed_jobs',
    ),          
),
```

and in my .env file:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

I feel like I must have something configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet but i believe that if you run this code snippet using cron then the things will be fixed.

```
Artisan::call('queue:work')
```